# Going to tomcat7 page even after uninstalling

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

I had completely uninstalled tomcat7 from my Ubuntu15.04. Even after uninstalling when i go to http://localhost:8080/
Below thing is being displayed

```
It works !

If you're seeing this page via a web browser, it means you've setup Tomcat successfully. Congratulations!

This is the default Tomcat home page. It can be found on the local filesystem at: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html

Tomcat7 veterans might be pleased to learn that this system instance of Tomcat is installed with CATALINA_HOME in /usr/share/tomcat7 and CATALINA_BASE in /var/lib/tomcat7, following the rules from /usr/share/doc/tomcat7-common/RUNNING.txt.gz.

You might consider installing the following packages, if you haven't already done so:

tomcat7-docs: This package installs a web application that allows to browse the Tomcat 7 documentation locally. Once installed, you can access it by clicking here.

tomcat7-examples: This package installs a web application that allows to access the Tomcat 7 Servlet and JSP examples. Once installed, you can access it by clicking here.

tomcat7-admin: This package installs two web applications that can help managing this Tomcat instance. Once installed, you can access the manager webapp and the host-manager webapp.

NOTE: For security reasons, using the manager webapp is restricted to users with role "manager-gui". The host-manager webapp is restricted to users with role "admin-gui". Users are defined in /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml.
```

I had also installed my tomcat8. How to go to tomcat8 page in browser?

Comment: Did you stop it before uninstalling? Maybe the process is still there and you didn't reboot?

Comment: Well i did. But still no luck.

Comment: Could the page still be in your browser cache?

Comment: how did you install tomcat? Was it an official package?

Answer (score 0):

try to use a different port number. Maybe tomcat 8 was installed with a different port

Comment: Even i had checked the port number in services.xml. Its same.

Answer (score 0):

Either process is running or the page is cached on your browser. If tomcat is running there will be a running java process. Try `ps -ef |grep java` to list the running java processes.

Comment: Yeah. I think, the page is cached on my browser. Now after sometimes automatically, i can go to tomcat8 admin page.